# Storing RGB in a unique variable

Tags: java, variables, gradient, rgb

Please keep in mind I am fairly new to Java but I should know enough to be helped with this and I should be able understand the information given to me for this question.

I want to store an RGB value into a variable and be able to increment it non-manually. In pseudo code what I want to do is this: place one 32p by 32p square at 0, 0 of the screen with the rgb value (0, 0, 0). Next I want to place another 32p by 32p square directly next to it with the rgb value (10, 0, 0) and so on giving a gradient of dark red to light red.

I figured out how to do this manually, but I was wondering if there was a way to be able to automate this in a loop so I wouldn't have to repeat this code constantly just to add one more square every time. I came up with this for you to look at so you could hopefully understand what I mean better (click the picture link below to see what I mean).

Any information given to me would be greatly appreciated :D

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5stq.jpg

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: You can make a Color object with any values you like for R, G and B.  I don't see what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like this:

```
for(int red = 0, yoffset = 0; red <= 255; red += 10, yoffset++)  {
   g.setColor(new Color(red, 0, 0));
   g.fillRect(0, y * yoffset, 32, 32);
}
```

Comment: This throws an IllegalArgumentException and earns a downvote.

Comment: Haha wow, yeah that works perfectly. Thanks  a lot. I didn't realize it was that easy.

Comment: @DavidWallace That's a bit harsh, it's probably only because he runs `red` till `5000` for some reason, while it cannot be higher than `255` I would imagine. The general principle of his answer still applies.

Comment: Changed so RGB is valid.

Comment: No, @DaniëlKnippers - people come to Stack Overflow looking for answers that actually work.  The site loses much of its value if it's full of broken code.

Comment: @DavidWallace Valid point; though I would argue in this case it was better to just edit the obvious mistake instead of down voting.

Comment: @user3426444: Glad it helped. Don't forget to up-vote and accept it as your answer, by clicking on the big green checkmark.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop incrementing a value from 0 to 7.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    g.setColor(new Color(10*i,0,0));
    g.fillRect(0,y*i,32,32);
}
```

This will increment i by 1 for every time the loop ends, and derive the color and position from that. It only draws the red bar - you add two more loops for the blue and green bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a lot less code if you use a loop over the values of 'y' you want to draw squares at. The colour at each point should be equal to the colour you want to go up to multiplied by the fraction of the way down the screen we are - so black at first, fully coloured at the end. For instance, for a red gradient:

```
int squareSize = 32;
int numSquares = 10;
int maxColour = 255;

for (int y = 0; y < (squareSize * numSquares); y+=squareSize) {
    // The red value is found using the fraction of the way down the gradient we've travelled
    // The bottom of the gradient is at squareSize * numSquares
    int colourValue = (maxColour * (y / (squareSize * numSquares)))
    g.setColor(new Color(colourValue, 0, 0));
    g.fillRect(0, y, squareSize, squareSize);
}
```

Note that I've pulled out things like the size of the squares into variables - this makes it a lot easier to make changes later as you won't have to go through making sure all the values you've used are consistent.